# There is [ms-access] but [msword]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently on SO there are tags [msword](/questions/tagged/msword) (2246) and [msaccess](/questions/tagged/msaccess) (8736) (also [ms-access-2007](/questions/tagged/ms-access-2007), etc.)

Let's re-synonymize `msword` to `ms-word` (not vice versa as currently) by analogy with `ms-access`?

Comment: I checked SU and they use the hyphenated versions for all their MS tags.  And *wow*, do they ever have a ton of them.